# How to disallow empty imports in eslint?

Tags: eslint, typescript-eslint

I've been trying to disallow empty imports like this:

```js
import {} from 'module-foo';
```

Does anybody know how to do it? (I have a TypeScript Node.js project.)

Comment: I suppose that would belong in https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-import, but it doesn't look like it has that rule now.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks, I am using this plugin already, but I haven't found a rule for this either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although there are no predefined rules for it, you can use [`no-restricted-syntax` rule](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-restricted-syntax) and [AST Selectors](https://eslint.org/docs/developer-guide/selectors) to disallow this certain syntax:

```js
// .eslintrc.js

module.exports = {
  // ... rest of the options
  rules: {
    // ... rest of the rules
    'no-restricted-syntax': [
      'error',
      {
        selector: 'ImportDeclaration[specifiers.length = 0]',
        message: 'Empty imports are not allowed',
      },
    ],
  }
}
```

Check [this AST Tree](https://astexplorer.net/#/gist/d10243a200e6ae68e3cd23855feaea59/latest) to understand how the selector is targeting empty import.

Comment: in my case, i wanted to allow only empty imports for styles, so I ended up using this selector `ImportDeclaration[specifiers.length = 0][source.value!=/\\.s?css$/]`. seems to work great.

Answer (score 1):

Farzad's solution gave me some problems like false positive or does not work in:

```js
import "package";
import PackageDefault, {} from "package";
```

I solved it with:

1. Run

```bash
npm install eslint-plugin-regex
```

2. Change you eslintrc

```json
{
    "plugins": [
        "regex"
    ],
    "rules": {
        "regex/invalid": [
            "error",
            [
                {
                    "id": "EmptyImport",
                    "message": "errorMessageN",
                    "regex": "import(.*{\\s*}.*)from",
                    "replacement": {
                        "function":
                            "return $[1].replace(/\\s/g, '') !== '{}' ? $[0].replace(/,?\\s{\\s*},?\\s/, ' ') : $[0]"
                    }
                }
            ]
        ],
    }

}
```

```markdown
### This rule suport eslint --fix
```

```js
import {} from "package"; // manual fixable
import package, {} from "package"; // import package from "package";
```

to automatically remove import voids during eslint fix:

```js
import {} from "package";
```

3. Use this rule in place of the other

```json
{
    "id": "EmptyImport",
    "message": "errorMessageN",
    "regex": "import(.*{\\s*}.*)from.*\\n",
    "replacement": {
        "function":
            "return $[1].replace(/\\s/g, '') !== '{}' ? $[0].replace(/,?\\s{\\s*}\\s/, ' ') : ''"
    }
}
```

Solution in MyLinter Package: ❤️
https://github.com/ODGodinho/ODG-Linter-Js/blob/cd4a67afc45f624ee34abab7814b7a245e5c00ad/rules/javascript/possible-errors.js#L36

you can download it if you want, it will avoid these and other errors:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@odg/eslint-config#installation